How to do this replacement? Match the variable, but not the function
I have the following expression:
$$\frac{\left(-2 \lambda  \lambda [\theta ]+\lambda [\theta ]^2+\lambda ^2+\lambda \right) \lambda '[\theta ]^2}{\lambda [\theta ]^2}$$
I want to replace every instance of $\lambda$ by $\lambda[\theta]$ such that the expression simplifies. Ofcourse the $\lambda[\theta]$ expression should not be matched, otherwise you get $\lambda[\theta][\theta]$. What's the best way to do this in Mathematica?

You can replace \[Lambda][\[Theta]] with \[Lambda] first, and then replace  \[Lambda] with \[Lambda][\[Theta]], just like:
((l + l^2 - 2 l l[t] + l[t]^2) Derivative[1][l][t]^2)/
  l[t]^2 /. {l[t] -> l, l'[t] -> lp} /. {l -> l[t], lp -> l'[t]}

